# How to detect if there isn't an item in a specific slot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect if there isn't any item in a specific slot. If the item is not there, one command should run. I tried this command but it won't resolve my problem

`/testforblock ~ ~ ~ dropper -1 {Items:[0:{Slot:4b}]}`

.. no results..

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to detect the existence of any item in that slot, and then invert the output. For example, you would run your command as normal:

```
/testforblock X Y Z minecraft:dropper -1 {Items:[{Slot:4b}]}
```

And then check the `SuccessCount` value of that command block. If it's 0, that command failed. Replace the coordinates with that of the above command block's coordinates:

```
/testforblock X Y Z minecraft:repeating_command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

And then the above command block will succeed if the other command block failed.